# How to retrieve 1 eth I send by mistake to my smart contract token?

Tags: metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp, cpp-ethereum

This is the contract as you see there's one eth there https://etherscan.io/address/0x19d71f00354ad302e89ca47e59b68917f9a871d7#code.

I still have ownership of contract.

---

My eth stuck in smart contracts. I tried all public functions bu not possible to get my eth by the public functions. I think I can get my eth back if I get access to private functions its not appearing in remix how to get access to my private functions?

---

Yes, I add it manually so open trading won't work, but when read my contract very well, there’s some private functions can fix everything but I don't know how to access the private functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call openTrading(), it will put all that in an LP and then send you the LP tokens, you'll be able to unwrap them and get *most* of your ETH back.

EDIT : Oh no never mind, you already created the pair manually, well, looks like you're fucked, then.

Comment: Yeah I came to the same conclusion  `manualSwap()` fails because the pair already exists

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, the only way to get ETH out of your contract is via the `sendETHToFee()` function and it will send ETH to the `_taxWallet`.

You can call `manualSwap()` from the `_taxWallet`, it will convert all its tokens to ETH then send you all its ETH (including the 1 ETH that is in there)

Comment: I tired to call manual swap but its give transaction will failed any way to fix this, how to contact you